# How to parse a single png formate Image into my android Imageview from XML

Tags: android, xml

I have downloaded the code from AndroidHive of customize list view but I don't want my image in list view I want to parse it from xml with a simple imageview

Comment: Can you be more specific? It is unclear as to what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please make sure that you have read "how to ask a good question". Following these guidelines will make it easier for others to answer, and the responses you get will be better and show up quicker. Details are described here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have the png image you can add that image in drawable folder
and then

```
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/image1" />
```

simply refer that image with android:src of imageview

OR you can use Glide library